# Does a certain matrix inequality imply that a matrix is negative definite?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, schur-complement

Suppose I have the matrix
\begin{align}
F_s&=\begin{bmatrix}
F_{1s}  & G \\
G^T & F_{2s}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
where $F_{1s},F_{2s}$ are symmetric matrices that are also negative definite. $F_s$ is negative definite if and only if the following matrix inequality holds:
\begin{align}
F_{2s}<G^TF^{-1}_{1s}G.
\end{align}

**My Question**

> Suppose that I replace $F_s$ with
>   \begin{align}
> F&=\begin{bmatrix}
> F_{1s}  & G_1 \\
> G_2 & F_{2s}
> \end{bmatrix}
> \end{align}
>   Is $F$ negative deinite if and only if the following matrix inequality holds:
>   \begin{align}
> F_{2s}<G_2F^{-1}_{1s}G_1?
> \end{align}

**Background**

This question occurred to me when reading the paper [On Partial Contraction Analysis for Coupled Nonlinear Oscillators](http://web.mit.edu/nsl/www/preprints/BioCyb04.pdf) section 2.2 (it is not necessary to read this section I am just giving some background). I am trying to solve a much larger problem that would be made significantly easier if $F_{2s}<G_2F^{-1}_{1s}G_1$ implied $F$ is negative definite.

**Attempt**

Because general properties of matrices are outside my field of expertise my first idea was to find a counter example. My best idea for a counter example is
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1  & a \\
b & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
where $a$ and $b$ are scalars. The inequality $F_{2s}<G_2F^{-1}_{1s}G_1$ becomes
\begin{align}
-1&<b(-1)a\\
1&>ab
\end{align} 
As the eigenvalues of the matrix are $\lambda_{1,2}=-1\pm\sqrt{ab}$, the matrix is negative definite if and only if $1>ab$. So the statement holds.

Obviously this is not a proof but I cannot think of how to prove the general case. A hint or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Definiteness of non-symmetric matrices is a strange concept.

Comment: I know. I have an strange case where it is much more difficult to verify $F_{2s}<G^TF^{-1}_{1s}G$ compared to $F_{2s}<G_2F^{-1}_{1s}G_1$.

Comment: A suggestion, that may or may not be useful, is that a matrix is negative definite if and only if its symmetrization is negative definite.

Comment: @AzJ You need to define the meaning of the statement $F_{2s}<G_2F_{1s}^{-1}G_1$.

Comment: Thanks @Malkoun any suggestion is appreciated. I am not sure it is useful but I will try using that information.

Comment: @user1551 Could you clarify what is confusing? $F_{2s}<G_2F^{-1}_{1s}G_1$ means that the matrix $F_{2s}-G_2F^{-1}_{1s}G_1$ is negative definite. Same as $F_{2s}<G^TF^{-1}_{1s}G$ implies $F_{2s}-G^TF^{-1}_{1s}G$ is negative definite.

Comment: @Malkoun $F_{2s}>G^TF_{1s}^{-1}G$ is the condition for $F_s$ to be positive definite if $F_{1s}$ and $F_{2s}$ are positive definite.

Comment: @Malkoun yes I am just trying to answer your confusion (also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement )

Comment: @AzJ $G_2F_{1s}^{-1}G_1$ is not necessarily symmetric, and so the issue remains: what do you mean by positive/negative definiteness of a non-symmetric matrix?

Comment: user1551 is right to push you to be more careful. The theorem you are using about minors as a criterion for negative-definiteness, assumes that the matrix you start with is symmetric. If the matrix $A$ you are interested is not symmetric, when you write $A$ is negative definite, do you mean that $v^T A v < 0$ for all non-zero $v$? I think this is the same as requiring that the symmetrization of $A$ is negative definite. But then, in your example, you would need $1 > \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2$, right?

Comment: Continuing on my previous comment, we can thus say, at least in your example, that if $A$ is negative definite, then $1 > \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 \geq ab$, using the arithmetic-geometric inequality. But if we have $1 > ab$, then one may still even have $\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 > 1 > ab$ for some values of $a$ and $b$. For instance, take $a = 0.5$ and $b=1.8$. So this is an example where your proposed inequality holds, but the matrix is not negative-definite, in the sense of my previous comment.